# Magento 2 Payflow pro

Tags: php, magento, magento2, payflowpro

I am using the Payflow pro payment method test mode status "Yes" in Magento 2. When customer checkout, Magento create the order and order status set to processing but there is no invoice is created.

My question is it a normal behaviour, Admin should create an invoice normally or when we use the real account means test mode "No" then it will also create the invoice?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Its normal. Admin should create invoice manually.

Comment: Thank you @Kul even when we will use the "Test Mode" even then adimn have a need to create an invoice?

Comment: Yes. In magento admin need to create invoice manually.